# Is it possible to automate android without enabling USB debugging?

Tags: android, adb, androidviewclient

I need to connect Android phone to my DUT through USB and I have to connect and disconnect the device, and I need to send/receive data from phone to DUT through phone UI, To automate this I have used adb through wifi, and to disconnect device from DUT I am disabling and enabling USB debugging. While doing that my adb connection I am loosing adb connection also, 
how can I automate this scenario?

And I am using AndroidViewClient to automate the android.

Answer (score 0):

[AndroidViewClient](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient)'s successor [Culebra Tester](http://culebra.dtmilano.com/) uses a network connection and a RESTful API to interact with the DUT, then you would be able to disconnect the device from USB after the network service has been started.

More information on **Culebra Tester** can be found on its public [github site](https://github.com/dtmilano/CulebraTester-public) or [wiki](https://github.com/dtmilano/CulebraTester-public/wiki).